# Device or resource busy when deleting a mounted file

Tags: linux, kubernetes

I'm trying to delete a file from a Kubernetes pod but I'm getting this error Device or resource busy and I have a volume mount for this file

Comment: ...and what is your programming question?

Comment: yes it will give the error if using the exec command or how you are trying it or using code to write/delete file?

Comment: Please check [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11238/how-to-get-over-device-or-resource-busy)

Comment: @HarshManvar I'm using exec on pod , editing file passed with no errors but the delete is raising this exception

Comment: @AbhijithChitrapu I did already

Comment: which type of volume are you using? PVC mounted ?